# How to do FFT with complex numbers - Ansi C code

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, frequency, ifft, c

I have a small issue.

I'm going to do FFT2 onto a matrix $X$, and the only library I have is FFTPack. FFTPack is the oldest FFT library, but it's one of the fastest and 100% portable too.

The problem with FFTPack is that it has no FFT2 function. Only FFTPack version 5.1 has FFT2 functions, but those functions are written in Fortran 77. My FFTPack is written in ANSI C (C89) code and is a little bit older library than version 5.1. So I missing FFT2 functionality. Written in Fortran 77 and converted to ANSI C code. The library was first made in K&R-standard from 1982.

Anyway.
When I do FFT on each row of the matrix $X$, then I get the same result as I do i MATLAB.

```
fft(X')
```

**Problem:**

The values from every row of $X$ when I do FFT, they are complex numbers. My FFTPack function cannot handle complex numbers because my compiler does not support C99 standard and above. Only C89 standard (Yes, I know....).

So is there any way to do FFT again onto the complex numbers by separate them so imaginary numbers will be in one part and the real numbers will be inside another part?

Here is the FFTPack 5.1 version:
https://github.com/jlokimlin/fftpack5.1

Comment: So, port a more modern (and that is really not a hard to achieve requirement here) version of fftpack, or use a different library (fits, maybe) or learn to link against the original Fortran fftpack?

Comment: And use a modern compiler. It worst case, transpile to c89.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you. I posted the FFTPack library that holds a FFT2 function. Great. But it's for Fortran 77. You think I can convert it to C-code?

Comment: Why would you? I said *link against Fortran*,

Comment: @MarcusMüller There is a reason why ANSI C is still used. It's long time C code that's going to live on for ever.

Comment: Fortan is older, and ANSI C is a bad idea in 2023, that's why we had a newer C standard. ANSI C is lacking all we've learned about portable code in the years after 1989.

Comment: It's sometimes a sad requirement that you have to use c89, but I'd recommend not glorifying it by attributing it properties that it was specifically lacking.

Comment: @MarcusMüller According to whom is ANSI C a bad idea? ANSI C codes works perfectly. It's just missing lots of features.

Comment: It has really bad portability due to the way it's underspecified. But let's talk about your problem: nobody but you know the C port of fftpack you're using - fftpack is really Fortran, not C, but various people at various points in time have ported in various ways various parts of fftpack to C - In different versions of C. So, you need to figure out yourself how your specific port represents complex numbers. It definitely does - everything an FFT does is complex on in and output

Comment: @euraad: why don't you just use a different library (FFTW for example) or roll your own?  The core FFT algorithm isn't all that complicated and there are plenty of code examples out there. Most libraries have way more stuff in them than most people every need so I can restrict a port or write to your specific requirements.

Comment: What @Hilmar said.  Probably everyone and their dog has a simple radix-2 Cooley-Tukey FFT in source code.  I thought I might have posted mine here, but I don't see it.  Lemme know if you want me to find my 4 decade old FFT code written in C.  I know I posted it to *comp.dsp*.

Comment: That. I meant to mention "FFTs" in my first comment, but my phone corrected that to "fits". Anyways, I mean, really, get a compiler from the last 30 years. Compilers had `_Complex` long before it appeared in C99. Of course, pre-standard implementations suffer lack of compatibility and portability (this very much bit us in a vector math library we're maintaining!), so, again, staying in a c89 compiler is generally undesirable for this very problem you're solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radix-2 FFT written in ANSI C.   This is really ducking old.

```
/*  
    A set of utility programs to compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT):
    
                        N-1
                    X[k] = SUM { x[n]exp(-j2(pi)nk/N) }
                        n=0
    
    and inverse Fast Fourier Transform (iFFT):
    
                            N-1
                    x[n] = 1/N SUM { X[k]exp(+j2(pi)nk/N) }
                            k=0
    
    To speed things up, multiplication by 1 and j are avoided.  The input, x[],
    is an array of complex numbers (pairs of doubles) of length N = 2^p.  The
    calling program supplies p = log2(N) not the array length, N.  The output
    is placed in BIT REVERSED order in x[].  Call bitreverse(x, p) to swap back
    to normal order, if needed.  However, iFFT(X, p, trigtbl) requires its input,
    X[], to be in bit reversed order making bit reversing unnecessary in some
    cases, such as fast convolution.  trigtbl is an array of doubles of length
    N/4 containing the sin function from 0 to pi/2 used to compute the FFT.
    Call sintable(trigtbl, p) ONLY ONCE before either FFT(x, p, trigtbl) or
    iFFT(X, p, trigtbl) to set up a sin table for FFT computation.
    
    Written in Megamax C (for the Mac) by Robert Bristow-Johnson (1985).
*/

/*
#include <complex.h>
*/

typedef struct {
    double real;
    double imag;
} complex;

#define Re(z) (z).real
#define Im(z) (z).imag

#define PI (3.1415926535897932587)

double sin();

FFT (x, p, trigtbl)
complex x[];
int p;
register double *trigtbl;
{
    register long length, step, stepsize, size;
    register complex *top, *bottom, *end;               /* top & bottom of FFT butterfly */
    complex temp;
    
    size = 1L<<p;
    end = x + size;
    
    length = size>>1;   
    size >>= 2;
    stepsize = 1L;
    while ( length > 1L) {
        top = x;
        while (top < end) {
            bottom = top + length;
            
            Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);          /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
            Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
            Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
            Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
            *bottom = temp;
            top++;
            bottom++;
            
            for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);      /* butterfly: twiddle = exp(-j�) */
                Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
                Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
                Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
                Re(*bottom) = Re(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] + Im(temp)*trigtbl[step];
                Im(*bottom) = Im(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(temp)*trigtbl[step];
                top++;
                bottom++;
            }
            
            Re(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);          /* butterfly: twiddle = -j */
            Im(temp) = Re(*bottom) - Re(*top);
            Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
            Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
            *bottom = temp;
            top++;
            bottom++;
            
            for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                Re(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);      /* butterfly: twiddle = -j*exp(-j�) */
                Im(temp) = Re(*bottom) - Re(*top);
                Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
                Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
                Re(*bottom) = Re(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] + Im(temp)*trigtbl[step];
                Im(*bottom) = Im(temp)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(temp)*trigtbl[step];
                top++;
                bottom++;
            }
            top = bottom;
        }
        stepsize <<= 1;
        length >>= 1;
    }
    
    top = x;
    bottom = x + 1;
    while (top <  end) {
        Re(temp) = Re(*top) - Re(*bottom);              /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
        Im(temp) = Im(*top) - Im(*bottom);
        Re(*top) += Re(*bottom);
        Im(*top) += Im(*bottom);
        *bottom = temp;
        top += 2;
        bottom += 2;
    }
}


iFFT (X, p, trigtbl)
complex X[];
int p;
register double *trigtbl;
{
    register long length, step, stepsize, size;
    double scale;
    register complex *top, *bottom, *end;               /* top & bottom of FFT butterfly */
    complex temp;
    
    size = 1L<<p;
    end = X + size;
    
    scale = 1.0/(double)size;
    top = X;
    bottom = X + 1;
    while (top <  end) {
        Re(temp) = (Re(*top) - Re(*bottom))*scale;      /* butterfly: twiddle = 1/N */
        Im(temp) = (Im(*top) - Im(*bottom))*scale;
        Re(*top) = (Re(*top) + Re(*bottom))*scale;
        Im(*top) = (Im(*top) + Im(*bottom))*scale;
        *bottom = temp;
        top += 2;
        bottom += 2;
    }
    
    length = 1L;
    size >>= 2;
    stepsize = size;
    while ( stepsize >= 1L) {
        length <<= 1;
        top = X;
        while (top < end) {
            bottom = top + length;
            
            temp = *bottom;                             /* butterfly: twiddle = 1 */
            Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
            Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
            Re(*top) += Re(temp);
            Im(*top) += Im(temp);
            top++;
            bottom++;
            
            for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                                                        /* butterfly: twiddle = exp(+j�) */
                Re(temp) = Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
                Im(temp) = Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] + Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
                Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
                Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
                Re(*top) += Re(temp);
                Im(*top) += Im(temp);
                top++;
                bottom++;
            }
            
            Re(temp) = -Im(*bottom);                    /* butterfly: twiddle = +j */
            Im(temp) = Re(*bottom);
            Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
            Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
            Re(*top) += Re(temp);
            Im(*top) += Im(temp);
            top++;
            bottom++;
            
            for (step = stepsize; step < size; step += stepsize) {
                                                        /* butterfly: twiddle = +j*exp(+j�) */
                Re(temp) = -Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
                Im(temp) = Re(*bottom)*trigtbl[size - step] - Im(*bottom)*trigtbl[step];
                Re(*bottom) = Re(*top) - Re(temp);
                Im(*bottom) = Im(*top) - Im(temp);
                Re(*top) += Re(temp);
                Im(*top) += Im(temp);
                top++;
                bottom++;
            }
            top = bottom;
        }
        stepsize >>= 1;
    }
}


sintable(trigtbl, p)
register double *trigtbl;
int p;
{
    register long size, i;
    double theta;
    
    size = 1L<<(p-2);
    theta = (PI/2.0)/(double)size;
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        trigtbl[i] = sin(theta*(double)i);
}


bitreverse (x, p)
register complex *x;
int p;
{
    complex temp;
    register long k, i, r, size, count;
    
    size = (1L<<p) - 1L;
    for (k = 1L; k < size; k++) {
        i = k;
        r = 0;
        for (count = size; count > 0; count >>= 1) {
            r <<= 1;
            r += (i & 0x00000001L);
            i >>= 1;
        }
        if (r > k) {
            temp = x[r];
            x[r] = x[k];
            x[k] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this really is **ducking** old! Love the K&R variable declaring between function stub and function body!

Comment: Ya know, I think you're right, @MarcusMüller .  This is K&R C and precedes ANSI C.  It was written very soon after I was married in 1985.   (I know it's after because my name is hyphenated.)

Comment: :) dating code that way definitely is cool; anyway, any compiler that actually supports ANSI C but not yet C99 will work happily with that code.

Comment: Them Aussies just dunno how to cuss down there down under.

Comment: Goosing unbelievable.

Comment: Old school C code is so cool :D

Answer (score 1):

Up until a few years ago, MS Visual Studio supported C only as C89. Which was a major pain in bigger projects locked into that IDE/compiler and multi-platform projects.

If possible, I would use a modern compiler and a modern library.

If fft size is moderate and speed is of little importance, you could just implement a complex DFT as a plain matrix multiplication using your own definition of complex on top of real numbers in C89?